# Juju add-subnet command fails to move existing subnet into a space

Tags: networking, juju, kubernetes

I have been following [this blog post](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/02/08/automate-the-deployment-of-kubernetes-in-existing-aws-infrastructure/) to deploy a minimal k8s cluster into my existing development VPC. I have created private and public space, but when I tried to use add-subnet to add my private and public subnets into the respective spaces it said that subnet already exists. When I run `juju subnets` it lists every subnet I have in the VPC. Is there any way for me to limit Juju to only be aware of the two subnets I have created for it and to move these subnets into correct spaces?

Here is the command I have tried:

```
juju add-subnet 10.10.10.0/24 public
```

And here is the output I get:

> ERROR cannot add subnet: adding subnet "10.10.10.0/24": subnet
>   "10.10.10.0/24" already exists

Another question is whether I can avoid deploying each piece of the k8s separately the way it describes in the blog and use kubernetes-core charm, but still specify the subnets and VPC I want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the current Juju release. I have created a bug report and posted both the description and workarounds I have found there. Here is a link

https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1749272